# How to pass view array from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I know this is just plain simple.. but I think I am missing on something, I get this error, I tried everything before posting here

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

**controller**

```
$temp = Servers::all();
        $data = array();
        foreach ($temp as $key) {
            $data[] = array(
                'srv_id'     => $key->srv_id,
                'srv_name'   => $key->srv_name,
                'srv_status' => $key->srv_status,
                'srv_files'  => $key->srv_files,
                'srv_disk'   => $this->ConvertBytes( $key->srv_disk ),
                'srv_ip'     => $key->srv_ip

                );
        }

return View::make( 'pages.server', compact( 'data' ) );
```

If I vardump the code this is what i get

**var_dump**

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["srv_id"]=>
    string(3) "389"
    ["srv_name"]=>
    string(3) "u02"
    ["srv_status"]=>
    string(2) "ON"
    ["srv_files"]=>
    string(5) "43832"
    ["srv_disk"]=>
    string(9) "520.07 Gb"
    ["srv_ip"]=>
    string(13) "89.39.196.138"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["srv_id"]=>
    string(3) "392"
    ["srv_name"]=>
    string(3) "u07"
    ["srv_status"]=>
    string(2) "ON"
    ["srv_files"]=>
    string(5) "42566"
    ["srv_disk"]=>
    string(9) "495.16 Gb"
    ["srv_ip"]=>
    string(13) "89.39.196.147"
  }
```

**view**
This is how I view my array in my page

```
@foreach($data as $server)
    <td>{{ $server['srv_id'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $server['srv_name'] }}</td>
```

Comment: Why go through that entire loop when you could just do ``$servers = Servers::all();``, pass ``compact('servers')`` to the view, and then do ``@foreach ($servers as $server) ... @endforeach``? Much shorter, and easier to read and maintain. :)

Comment: Of course I can do that but, I wrapped an element in a function that is found within the controller.. and I can't call that function in my view

Comment: I'd argue that the method probably belongs on the model, then. No matter, at least you got the problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error message is because the data in `$temp` is an array and your trying to access it as an object. Try this instead.

```
$temp = Servers::all();
$data = array();
foreach ($temp as $key) {
    $data[] = array(
        'srv_id'     => $key['srv_id'],
        'srv_name'   => $key['srv_name'],
        'srv_status' => $key['srv_status'],
        'srv_files'  => $key['srv_files'],
        'srv_disk'   => $this->ConvertBytes( $key['srv_disk'] ),
        'srv_ip'     => $key['srv_ip']
    );
}
```

Arrays can be accessed like so:

```
$foo['bar'];
```

While objects can be accessed like so:

```
$foo->bar;
```